# AutoCompleteTextView does not display all your options when you press the field

Tags: java, android-studio, autocompletetextview

I'm trying to make my `AutoCompleteTextView` variable called `autoCategory_book` show all of its options just by pressing on the field.

- There are several errors pointed out on the same line:

```
// expected ')', expected ';', expected '(', expected '{', cannot resolve symbol 'view', cannot resolve symbol 'b' unexpected token 
autoCategoty_book.setOnFocusChangeListener(View.OnFocusChangeListener(view , b -> if(b) autoCategory_book.showDropDown()));
```

- `string.xml`

```
    <string-array name="category_book">
        <item> Self help </item>
        <item> Biography </item>
        <item> Education </item>
        <item> Science fiction </item>
        <item> Manual </item>
        <item> Literature </item>
        <item> Romance </item>
    </string-array>
```

- `RegisterBook.java`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AutoCompleteTextView autoCategory_book;
    String[] Category_book;
    
    Category_book = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.category_book);
    
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Category_book);
    autoCategory_book.setThreshold(0);
    autoCategory_book.setAdapter(adapter);
    autoCategoty_book.setOnFocusChangeListener(View.OnFocusChangeListener(view , b -> if(b) autoCategory_book.showDropDown()));

}
```

Comment: what happens if you remove the focusListener?

Comment: @DJ.Aduvanchik didn't decide to remove the ```OnFocusChangeListener```

Comment: you don't need to have the View.onFocusChangeListener
    autoCategory_book.setOnFocusChangeListener((v, hasFocus) ->{
                if(hasFocus){
autoCategory_book.showDropDown();
                }
                }
        );

Comment: @DJ.Aduvanchik please convert this comment as an answer, the way it is formatted is confusing for me to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need `View.onFocusChangeListener`:

```
autoCategory_book.setOnFocusChangeListener((v, hasFocus) ->{
      if(hasFocus){ autoCategory_book.showDropDown(); 
     );
```